# How to calculate the resolution of an image?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

How to determine the resolution (Width x Height) of an image (Mat format) with OpenCV?

I have a thread that receives many images..one at time. I want to determine the resolution of an image, when the thread receives it (to obtain dimension of width and height in pixel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
cv::Mat someMat;
int width;
int height;

width = someMat.cols;
height = someMat.rows;
```

or:

```
width = someMat.size().width;
height = someMat.size().height;
```

Comment: One more thing, opencv has a great documentation here http://docs.opencv.org/ you can find all you need to know about opencv here.

Answer (score 2):

For a `Mat mat`, you can simply use the following to get its dimension (width and height):

```
int width = mat.cols;
int height = mat.rows;
```